# Existence of global solution of Riccati equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

Consider a Riccati differential equation
$$
  \dot P + A(t)^{T}P + PA(t) -PB(t)R(t)B(t)^{T}P + Q(t) = 0,\;\;\; P(t_0) = P_0 = P_0^{T} \geqslant 0
$$
where $Q(t) = Q(t)^{T} \geqslant 0$, $R(t) = R(t)^{T} > 0$, all matrices are real and continuous. How to show that for any $t_0$ there exists (and unique) a solution defined on $(-\infty,t_0]$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The uniqueness of solution, when $P$ remains continuous, as well as the existence of a local solution, follows from Picard-Lindelof. Hence it remains to establish that $P$ doesn't blow-up in finite time. It is clear from the form of the evolution equation that $P$ will remain symmetric. Hence it suffices to show that $P$ has eigenvalues bounded above and below. A sketch of the idea of the proof:

1. $P \geq 0$ in $(-\infty,t_0]$. This follows from the sign on $Q$. Let $\tau\in (-\infty,t_0]$ be the smallest time such that $P$ is positive semidefinite on $[\tau,t_0]$. Necessarily, there exists some vector $v\in \ker P(\tau)$ and some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $v^TP(t)v < 0$ for all $t\in (\tau-\epsilon,\tau)$. However, for $v\in \ker P$, we have that 
   $$ v^T\dot{P}v + (Av)^TPv + v^TPAv - v^TPBRB^TPv + v^TQv = v^T\dot{P}v + v^TQv = 0 $$
   Using that $Q$ is positive semidefinite, we see that it is impossible for *increase* to 0 from somewhere negative.
2. $P$ cannot blow-up in finite backwards time. Since $PBRB^TP$ is by definition a positive semi-definite form, we have that 
   $$ -\dot{P} \leq A^TP + PA + Q $$
   which implies that in backwards time, the growth of $P$ cannot exceed that of the linear equation $-\dot{P} = A^TP + PA + Q$. Since the latter cannot blow-up in finite time, the same is true for the original equation.

---

Let me work out the scalar case in more detail (mainly for convenience of notation, since integrating factors are a bit easier to write when the products commute). From this you can see how to write it up for the matrix case.

The analogous scalar equation is
$$ \dot{p} + 2ap - rp^2 + q = 0 $$
where $q,r$ are non-negative functions, and $p$ is given initial data $p(t_0) \geq 0$. Let $\alpha(t) = \int_{t_0}^t 2a(s)\mathrm{d}s$. And write $\tilde{p} = e^{\alpha}p$. We have that
$$ \dot{\tilde{p}} = e^\alpha\left(\dot{p} + 2a p\right) = e^\alpha (rp^2 - q) $$
So that
$$ \dot{\tilde{p}} = e^{-\alpha}r \tilde{p}^2 - e^\alpha q $$

Now since $e^\alpha$ is positive, we have that $\tilde{r} = e^{-\alpha}r$ is still non-negative, as is $\tilde{q} = e^\alpha q$.

For the equation 
$$ \dot{\tilde{p}} = \tilde{r} \tilde{p}^2 - \tilde{q} $$
upper boundedness in backwards time is immediate. Since we have that
$$ \dot{\tilde{p}} \geq -\tilde{q} \implies \tilde{p}(t) - \tilde{p}(t_0) \leq \int_{t}^{t_0} \tilde{q}(s) \mathrm{d}s$$

For lower boundedness we see that on an interval $[t_1,t_2]$ on which $p$ is non-vanishing, we must have that
$$ \dot{\tilde{p}} \leq \tilde{r} \tilde{p}^2 \implies \frac{1}{\tilde{p}(t_1)} - \frac{1}{\tilde{p}(t_2)} \leq \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \tilde{r}(s)\mathrm{d}s $$
hence if $\tilde{p}(t_1) < 0$ at some point, $\tilde{p}$ cannot approach 0 in finite time to the future. The contrapositive implies that since $\tilde{p}(t_0) \geq 0$, for every $\tau < t_0$ we cannot have $\tilde{p}(\tau) < 0$, establishing the lower-bound. This last argument, however, is not so easy to translate to the matrix case. So instead, let me give another one which is easier to use in the matrix case.

As before, suppose $\tilde{p} = 0$ at some point $\tau < t_0$ and $\tilde{p} < 0$ in $[\tau - \epsilon,\tau)$ (the existence of the solution, and its continuity on this interval, we assume by appealing to the local existence part of Picard-Lindelof). We can further assume that $0\leq \int_{\tau-\epsilon}^\tau \tilde{r}(\sigma) \tilde{p}(\sigma)\mathrm{d}\sigma < \frac12$, by choosing $\epsilon$ sufficiently small. We have the expression 
$$ \dot{\tilde{p}} \leq \tilde{r} \tilde{p}^2 $$
Now let $\tau' \in [\tau-\epsilon,\tau)$ be a point where $\tilde{p}$ achieves its minimum (in that interval). Integrate from $\tau'$ to $\tau$ we get
$$  - \tilde{p}(\tau') = |\tilde{p}(\tau')| \leq \int_{\tau'}^\tau \tilde{r}|\tilde{p}|^2 \mathrm{d}\sigma $$
Using the integral bound we assumed we have
$$ |\tilde{p}(\tau')| \leq \frac12 \sup_{\sigma\in[\tau',\tau]} |\tilde{p}(\sigma)| = \frac12 |\tilde{p}(\tau')|$$
which can only occur if $\tilde{p}(\tau') = 0$. This shows that it is impossible to have $\tilde{p}(\tau') < 0$ and $\tilde{p}(\tau) = 0$ with $\tau' < \tau$.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer!

Comment: @ValerySaharov: basic idea is that for something to go from $< 0$ to $=0$ there must be a point where it is very small in absolute value. But then the negative source term will dominate all linear and nonlinear terms, and so you will bounce away from zero again. If you understand why, when solving the ODE $\dot{y} = y + y^2$ with negative initial data, you cannot reach $y = 0$ in finite time, then you should be able to see why point 1 holds.

Comment: If you cannot find $v$ such that $v^T P v$ changes sign, then $P$ is always positive semi-definite, and you are done. Therefore you assume such an object exists and argue by contradiction. // I don't have a reference, but the idea is simple enough that I don't dare to claim as "mine". @ValerySaharov

Comment: @ValerySaharov: If $v^T Pv$ is increasing, then $v^T \dot{P} v \geq 0$. By assumption ditto $v^T Q v \geq 0$. In the case one of the two is strictly positive you have an obvious contradiction. To rule out the case both of them are zero see the final paragraph or so of the answer. // Did you read past the sketch? Did you try reading through the scalar ODE argument below the cut and adapting it to the matrix case?

Comment: @Willie Wong: Thank you for your clarification. I understand the scalar example and had difficulty to generalize it to the matrix case. Could you please elaborate more or recommend some reference material to me? Thank you very much.